# Custom validation class not loading in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to write my own validation class in Laravel 4. To do this, I created a new directory called `app/validators`. I then added this directory to the `composer.json` classmap and ran `composer update`, like so:

```
"classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/controllers",
    "app/models",
    "app/validators",           <- added here
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php"
]
```

My validation class looks like this:

```
class LinkValidation extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {
{
    public function validateHost($field, $value, $params)
    {
        return $value == 'test';
    }
}
```

and in my controller, I'm trying to extend the validator like so:

```
Validator::extend('awesome', 'LinkValidation@supportedHost');
```

However, I'm getting this error when loading a page:

```
{
    "error":{
        "type":"ReflectionException",
        "message":"Class LinkValidation does not exist",
        "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php",
        "line":301
    }
}
```

Any ideas why Laravel won't load the class? I thought it'd do it automatically if added to composer's classmap.

Comment: The command to update the autoloader file is `composer dump-autoload`. Documentation here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it isn't working, but I think you should try adding it in *app/start/global.php*.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Laravel Class Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| In addition to using Composer, you may use the Laravel class loader to
| load your controllers and models. This is useful for keeping all of
| your classes in the "global" namespace without Composer updating.
|
*/

ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/validators',

));
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! I'd still prefer doing it via composer just for consistency however this will do for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Always do `composer dumpautoload` after create new class object.